# FAT32 External HDD won't open in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, external-hard-drive, fat32

I run both Ubuntu and Windows 7 machines. I would like to use an external HDD. I read that if it is formatted to FAT32 bot OS's should read it. Win7 is not reading it. How do I get Windows to read/open a FAT32 formatted HDD?

When I go to `Devices and Printers` I can see the disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you have formatted the entire drive as FAT32, without splitting it into partitions, Windows might get confused (I think). If that's the case, you'll need to backup all your data, partition the external drive (which will **destroy all your data**), using e.g. fdisk (text-based) or gparted (GUI), and create a new FAT32 partition. You don't have to create any other partitions.

Answer (score 0):

it could be a drive letter issue. go to Disk Management and try assigning it another drive letter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The option `Change Drive Letter and Paths...` is grayed out.